# How to filter unique values with jq?

Tags: bash, gcloud, jq

I'm using the gcloud describe command to get metadata information about instances.What's the best way to filter the json response with jq to get the name of the instance - if it contains "kafka" as a key.

.name + " " + .metadata.items[]?.key | select(contains("kafka"))'

Basically if items contains kafka print name.This is just a small excerpt from the json file.

```
  "metadata": {
    "fingerprint": "xxxxx=",
    "items": [
      {
        "key": "kafka",
        "value": "xxx="
      },
      {
        "key": "some_key",
        "value": "vars"
      }
    ],
    "kind": "compute#metadata"
  },
  "name": "instance-name",
  "networkInterfaces": [
    {
      "accessConfigs": [
        {
          "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
          "name": "External NAT",
          "natIP": "ip",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
        }
      ],
      "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
      "name": "",
      "network": xxxxx
    }
  ],
```

Comment: jq has a [`unique`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by\(path_exp\)) function.

Comment: The given snippet does not contain "name" and indeed is not valid JSON. Please provide a minimal complete verifiable example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure this is possible with `jq`, but in general working with gcloud lists is going to be easier using the built-in formatting and filtering:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list \
     --filter 'metadata.items.key:kafka' \
     --format 'value(name)'
```

`--filter` tells you which items to pick; in this case, it grabs the instance metadata, looks at the items, and checks the keys for those containing `kafka` (use `=` instead to look for keys that are *exactly* `kafka`).

`--format` tells you to grab just one `value()` (as opposed to a table, JSON, YAML) from each matching item; that item will be the `name` of the instance.

You can learn more by running `gcloud topic filters`, `gcloud topic formats`, and `gcloud topic projections`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple jq solution using **if** and **any**:

```
      if .metadata.items | any(.key == "kafka") then . else empty end
    | .name
```